# How can I measure linq queries execution time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I've got newsletter site developed using ASP.NET MVC 2 and I use LINQ to access data from database. Unfortunately site perfomance is in a terrible state. Loading time of the pages is too slow. And now I want to determine weak areas of the Web-Application. First of all I want to measure execution time of my LINQ queries and optize it.

Are there any tools or techniques to do that? Or what steps should I take to detect problem queries and compare execution time before and after optimisation?

Upd: ASP.NET MVC 2 and .NET 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start with  Stackoverflow's own [MVC Mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/). It supports database profiling as well with Linq to SQL and Linq to Entities.

Once you get down to problems in the generated SQL queries there is always [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) or paid products like [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say about .NET 3.5. Judging by [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) project not supported by .NET 3.5 quote: _Does this project work with .NET 3.5?
No, we only support .NET 4.0_

Comment: I would suggest you take a look the sql generated.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is to start sql profiler and watch the sql statement sent to the SQL server. LINQ sometimes generate inefficient SQL.